# Chart.js Currency Tooltip

Tags: chart.js

I have plain old data like this:

```
type: "donut",
data: {
    labels: ['Budgeted', 'Over Budget', 'Remaining'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [100, 20, 0],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#1ab394',
            '#ed5565',
            '#e7e7e7'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            '#1ab394',
            '#ed5565',
            '#e7e7e7'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
}
```

Trying to make the tooltips currency format:

```
  options: {
    legend: false,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return '$' + tooltipItem.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I get the `$` but nothing else - I am new to Chart.js and I am sure I am missing something small / obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the snippet below, which shows "$100" and "$20" labels in the tooltip.

I didn't really change your code, just put it all together.  Make sure your code looks like this, and if you're doing something different please update your post!

```js
const config = {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Budgeted", "Over Budget", "Remaining"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [100, 20, 0],
        backgroundColor: ["#1ab394", "#ed5565", "#e7e7e7"],
        borderColor: ["#1ab394", "#ed5565", "#e7e7e7"],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    legend: false,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
          return (
            "$" +
            tooltipItem.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
          );
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3"></script>

<canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```